# updating unread_count to facebook mailbox as READ messages

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have developed an iPhone application in which I am fetching private messages and reading them. But once I read any messages, I want to update its unread_count as "read" to facebook. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Marking messages as read is currently is currently a limitation of the Facebook API, and cannot be done.